# How do I check if an array have 2 of the same value? - java

Tags: arrays, duplicates

I have a school task where you are supposed to make a method that checks if a already made array has 2 numbers of the same value. I am supposed to check it with a parameter

I have tried this one, but this only check if the number IS in the array, and then returns true if it finds it. But how do I check if the same number is in the array 2 or more times?

```
public boolean checkArray(int checkThisNumber){
for(int number: array){
    if(checkThisNumber==number){
     duplicates=true;
     }
         }

            return duplicates;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a boolean check in the if statement, try using a counter.
Then check to see if the counter is greater than 1.

You can use a single return statement to check if something is true or false;

```
return (x > 1);
```

I'm not going to write the code for you, because that would be counter productive.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Something likes this then?

```
public boolean checkArray(int checkNumber){

           int counter=0;
            for(int number: array){
                if(number==checkNumber){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if(counter>=2){
                duplicates=true;
            }

            return duplicates;
        }
```